# content in recyclerview not changing when language changed

Tags: java, android, localization

I have done with values, values-in, and values-en. but my data in recyclerview still not change.
When i try to change language content which not include in recyclerview is changing but content that include in recyclerview can't changing

i have done trying recreate but it's not working

**data Tv**

```
package com.example.submission2.Data;

import android.content.Context;

import com.example.submission2.ItemData;
import com.example.submission2.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TvShow {

private static Context context;
private static ArrayList<ItemData> itemDataTvs;

public TvShow(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

private static final int[] PROFILE = {
        R.drawable.tv_poster_arrow,
        R.drawable.tv_poster_doom_patrol,
        R.drawable.tv_poster_dragon_ball,
        R.drawable.tv_poster_iron_fist,
        R.drawable.tv_poster_family_guy,
        R.drawable.tv_poster_flash,
        R.drawable.tv_poster_god,
        R.drawable.tv_poster_gotham,
        R.drawable.tv_poster_grey_anatomy,
        R.drawable.tv_poster_hanna
};

public static ArrayList<ItemData> getAllTv(){
    itemDataTvs = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] desc = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.DescriptionTv);
    String[] tanggal = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.TanggalTv);
    String[] judul = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.TittleTv);
    String[] score = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ScoreTv);


    for(int i = 0; i < PROFILE.length;i++){
        ItemData itemDataTv = new ItemData();

        itemDataTv.setProfil(PROFILE[i]);
        itemDataTv.setDataPublish(tanggal[i]);
        itemDataTv.setTitle(judul[i]);
        itemDataTv.setDescription(desc[i]);
        itemDataTv.setScor(score[i]);

        itemDataTvs.add(itemDataTv);
    }
    return itemDataTvs;
}
```

}

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.submission2;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.example.submission2.Data.Movies;
import com.example.submission2.Data.TvShow;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabLayout tabs;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Movies movies = new Movies(this);
    TvShow tvShow = new TvShow(this);

    sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
    tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_setting){
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(mIntent);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

**PagerAdapter**

```
package com.example.submission2;

import android.content.Context;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import com.example.submission2.Data.Movies;
import com.example.submission2.Data.TvShow;

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final int[] TAB_TITLES = new int[]{
        R.string.tab_text_1,
        R.string.tab_text_2
};

private final Context mContext;

public SectionsPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, Context mContext) 
{
    super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = TabFragment.newInstance(Movies.getAllMovies());
    switch (position){
        case 0 :
            fragment = TabFragment.newInstance(Movies.getAllMovies());
            break;
        case 1 :
            fragment = TabFragment.newInstance(TvShow.getAllTv());
            break;
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mContext.getResources().getString(TAB_TITLES[position]);
}
}
```

Comment: I noticed you are storing your strings to an array.  Are you updating the String Array after you change languages?  Once the strings are in the array, the values will not change until you refresh them from the strings xml data.

Comment: yes your right, i store my string to array. so how to update string Array @smitty1?

Comment: Can you show the code where tvShow.getAllTv() is being called?

Comment: in pageradapter my fragment @smitty1

Answer (score 0):

Once you put the actual Strings into an array, the Strings won't be refreshed until you call the getAllTv() method again.  The best I can suggest is instead of storing the actual Strings, change your logic to store the resource id of the string array resource and the index of the string within the array and then don't create the actual String until you are ready to display it in your RecyclerView adapter.  This way you can refresh the data in your RecyclerView adapter whenever the language changes and it will pull the string from the correct string resource.

You can use a BroadCastReceiver to detect when the Locale, and by association the language, changes and refresh your dataset:

```
 BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // refresh your adapter dataset and notify dataset changed here
        }

    };

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```